# SyncTeX wrongly placed when XeTeX called with -aux-directory

Tags: xetex, miktex, auxiliary-files, forward-inverse-search

I am using MikTeX 2.9 and compiling "hello.tex" containing:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

with:

```
xelatex --synctex=1 --aux-directory=auxdir hello.tex
```

produces a `E:\something.synctex.gz` instead of `hello.synctex.gz` in the same directory with the source `hello.tex`. In particular, "something" is the same length as "hellow.tex", indicating that SyncTeX is fed with the wrong path. This problem does not arise if pdflatex is called instead.

I have been using this command for a long time without any problems, but after updating my distribution the previous problem arose.

Any help will be much appreciated. If it turns out to be a bug, please tell me to which bug list I should report it.

Comment: It is a bug and I made a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3425223&group_id=10783&atid=110783

Comment: Thank you, by the way I have updated again from yesterday and the more recent version of miktex-xetex-bin-2.9 still has the bug, although it now places the .synctex.gz file in the same directory. This allows a temporary workaround for anyone using a makefile to compile, issue rm ./*.synctex.gz, then xelatex whatever and finally cp ./*.synctex.gz $(main_file).synctex.gz, where $(main_file) is your .tex filename. This is a temporary work-around until the bug gets fixed.

Comment: After the previous work-around, it turns out that the generated .synctex.gz is not properly aligned with the source tex. It is offset by a line and this remains even when not using the --aux-directory option.

Comment: Update from the buglist: the bug concerning the SyncTeX file name and placement has been fixed and will be available with the next update cycle of MikTeX. It remains to see whether the mismatched alignment issue between .pdf and .tex will remain.

Comment: If not: you know now where to make bug reports. (I'm not using synctex and so can't test problems.).

Comment: Thanks for reporting the bug, it has been fixed in xetex-bin-2.9 update of 18 Oct. The issue of wrong alignment in xelatex and synctex is due to X,Y offsets set to 0 within the synctex file. Using command line option -no-pdf when running xelatex produces the correct synctex file, although it does not produce a pdf. For more information [tex-live mailing list](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2011-August/030032.html). As noted there, this is intentional. Nonetheless, xelatex produces only pdf output.

Comment: Well the thread sounds for me as if there was a bug. Perhaps the correction didn't reach miktex. You could ask Akira about the details and if miktex should do something (and what).